# when zooming or moving iosmap it jumps always back to userlocation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, core-location

How can I stop the map bouncing back to userlocation always when the map is moved ? 
The lines responsible for that are the following:

```
 func locationAuthStatus(){
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse{
        map.showsUserLocation = true
    } else {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}


func centerMapOnLocation(location:CLLocation){

    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius * 2 , regionRadius * 2)
    map.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)

}



 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation){
if let location = userLocation.location {
    //this is the place where you get the new location


    print("\(location.coordinate.latitude) ")

    print("\(location.coordinate.longitude)")

}
 if let loc = userLocation.location {
    centerMapOnLocation(location: loc)
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


}
      }
```

I thought locationManager.stopUpdationglocation() would handle this problem but it seems as if he is instantly updating it when the map is moved. 
Though it should still update the users location from time to time like a map normally does.

Answer (score 0):

> This happened because you calling **centerMapOnLocation** on mapview update Delegate. So that it called everytime when mapview reload.
>
> SO that Call this function only that time where you allocate annotation pin for User location.
>
> > Like:

```
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(strLatitude)!) , longitude: CLLocationDegrees(Double(strLogitude)!)), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))
                        
self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```